# Parsing JSON using GSON with multiple inner objects.

Tags: java, json, rest, gson, opendaylight

I would like to parse the following JSON response, using GSON. As you can see, there are a lot of inner json objects in the response. Do I need to create POJO classes for all the inner objects or is there any alternative?

```
{
    "nodeProperties": [
        {
            "properties": {
                "timeStamp": {
                    "value": 1400475483694,
                    "name": "connectedSince"
                },
                "macAddress": {
                    "value": "00:00:00:00:00:03"
                },
                "tables": {
                    "value": -1
                },
                "capabilities": {
                    "value": 199
                },
                "tier": {
                    "value": 1
                },
                "supportedFlowActions": {
                    "value": "[Controller, Drop, Enqueue, HwPath, Output, PopVlan, SetDlDst, SetDlSrc, SetNwDst, SetNwSrc, SetNwTos, SetTpDst, SetTpSrc, SetVlanId, SetVlanPcp, SwPath]"
                },
                "buffers": {
                    "value": 256
                },
                "description": {
                    "value": "NEXT_NEWSwitch3"
                },
                "forwarding": {
                    "value": 0
                }
            },
            "node": {
                "id": "00:00:00:00:00:00:00:03",
                "type": "OF"
            }
        },
        {
            "properties": {
                "timeStamp": {
                    "value": 1400475481261,
                    "name": "connectedSince"
                },
                "macAddress": {
                    "value": "00:00:00:00:00:02"
                },
                "tables": {
                    "value": -1
                },
                "capabilities": {
                    "value": 199
                },
                "tier": {
                    "value": 1
                },
                "supportedFlowActions": {
                    "value": "[Controller, Drop, Enqueue, HwPath, Output, PopVlan, SetDlDst, SetDlSrc, SetNwDst, SetNwSrc, SetNwTos, SetTpDst, SetTpSrc, SetVlanId, SetVlanPcp, SwPath]"
                },
                "buffers": {
                    "value": 256
                },
                "description": {
                    "value": "None"
                },
                "forwarding": {
                    "value": 0
                }
            },
            "node": {
                "id": "00:00:00:00:00:00:00:02",
                "type": "OF"
            }
        },
        {
            "properties": {
                "timeStamp": {
                    "value": 1400475478695,
                    "name": "connectedSince"
                },
                "macAddress": {
                    "value": "00:00:00:00:00:01"
                },
                "tables": {
                    "value": -1
                },
                "capabilities": {
                    "value": 199
                },
                "supportedFlowActions": {
                    "value": "[Controller, Drop, Enqueue, HwPath, Output, PopVlan, SetDlDst, SetDlSrc, SetNwDst, SetNwSrc, SetNwTos, SetTpDst, SetTpSrc, SetVlanId, SetVlanPcp, SwPath]"
                },
                "buffers": {
                    "value": 256
                },
                "description": {
                    "value": "None"
                },
                "forwarding": {
                    "value": 0
                }
            },
            "node": {
                "id": "00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01",
                "type": "OF"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: The `gson` library makes it easy and simple to convert `JSON` object to **classes** in java. If you want these objects represented as classes, then **yes** you need to make POJO classes. If you do not necessarily want that (i.e. To convert the `JSON` to a **Map** or something) you shouldn't use `gson`

Comment: Whoever created that JSON was not too bright, but it's a simple matter to parse it into Maps and Lists that exactly mirror the JSON structure.  Generally GSON and Jackson are not good choices for this, though.

Comment: @HotLicks Can you please explain why you think the JSON structure is not good?

Comment: Rather than "forwarding : { value : 0 }", etc, it should be "forwarding : 0" (with appropriate quotes added, of course).  The extra layer of object adds nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply convert the JSON string into Map.

Sample code:

```
FileReader in = new FileReader(new File("resources/json3.txt"));
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);

// Convert JSON string into MAP object
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, ArrayList<Map<String, Map<String, Object>>>>>() {}.getType();
Map<String, ArrayList<Map<String, Map<String, Object>>>> map = gson.fromJson(br, type);

for (String key : map.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(key);
    for (Map<String, Map<String, Object>> value : map.get(key)) {
        for (String k : value.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(k);
            for (String k1 : value.get(k).keySet()) {
                System.out.println(k1 + ":" + value.get(k).get(k1));
            }
        }
        System.out.println("--------------");
    }
}

in.close();
br.close();
```

---

You can do it using some POJO classes as well which are replica of the JSON string that is more simple and shorter.

Sample code:

```
class PropertiesNode {
    Properties properties;
    Node node;
    // getter & setter
}

class Node {
    String id;
    String type;
    // getter & setter
}

class Properties {
    Map<String, Object> timeStamp;
    Map<String, String> macAddress;
    Map<String, Integer> tables;
    Map<String, Integer> capabilities;
    Map<String, Integer> tier;
    Map<String, String> supportedFlowActions;
    Map<String, Integer> buffers;
    Map<String, String> description;
    Map<String, Integer> forwarding;
    // getter & setter
}

Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, ArrayList<PropertiesNode>>>() {}.getType();
Map<String, ArrayList<PropertiesNode>> nodeProperties = gson.fromJson(br, type);
System.out.println(new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(nodeProperties).toString());
```

output:

```
{
    "nodeProperties": [
      {
        "properties": {
          "timeStamp": {
            "value": 1.400475483694E12,
            "name": "connectedSince"
          },
          "macAddress": {
            "value": "00:00:00:00:00:03"
          },
          "tables": {
            "value": -1
          },
          "capabilities": {
            "value": 199
          },
          "tier": {
            "value": 1
          },
          "supportedFlowActions": {
            "value": "[Controller, Drop, Enqueue, HwPath, Output, PopVlan, SetDlDst, SetDlSrc, SetNwDst, SetNwSrc, SetNwTos, SetTpDst, SetTpSrc, SetVlanId, SetVlanPcp, SwPath]"
          },
          "buffers": {
            "value": 256
          },
          "description": {
            "value": "NEXT_NEWSwitch3"
          },
          "forwarding": {
            "value": 0
          }
        },
        "node": {
          "id": "00:00:00:00:00:00:00:03",
          "type": "OF"
        }
      },
      {
        "properties": {
          "timeStamp": {
            "value": 1.400475481261E12,
            "name": "connectedSince"
          },
          "macAddress": {
            "value": "00:00:00:00:00:02"
          },
          "tables": {
            "value": -1
          },
          "capabilities": {
            "value": 199
          },
          "tier": {
            "value": 1
          },
          "supportedFlowActions": {
            "value": "[Controller, Drop, Enqueue, HwPath, Output, PopVlan, SetDlDst, SetDlSrc, SetNwDst, SetNwSrc, SetNwTos, SetTpDst, SetTpSrc, SetVlanId, SetVlanPcp, SwPath]"
          },
          "buffers": {
            "value": 256
          },
          "description": {
            "value": "None"
          },
          "forwarding": {
            "value": 0
          }
        },
        "node": {
          "id": "00:00:00:00:00:00:00:02",
          "type": "OF"
        }
      },
      {
        "properties": {
          "timeStamp": {
            "value": 1.400475478695E12,
            "name": "connectedSince"
          },
          "macAddress": {
            "value": "00:00:00:00:00:01"
          },
          "tables": {
            "value": -1
          },
          "capabilities": {
            "value": 199
          },
          "supportedFlowActions": {
            "value": "[Controller, Drop, Enqueue, HwPath, Output, PopVlan, SetDlDst, SetDlSrc, SetNwDst, SetNwSrc, SetNwTos, SetTpDst, SetTpSrc, SetVlanId, SetVlanPcp, SwPath]"
          },
          "buffers": {
            "value": 256
          },
          "description": {
            "value": "None"
          },
          "forwarding": {
            "value": 0
          }
        },
        "node": {
          "id": "00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01",
          "type": "OF"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Braj. Though this works, I chose to create POJOs for member variables in class Properties, instead of maps.